# Fetch Job Logs, and their messages from IBM machine

Tags: c#, ibm-midrange

Trying to develop C# application to fetch a list of Job under a sub system, and retrieve their messages.  I see there is a great example for Java, for getting stats on a job using the OpenJT ([is there any way to determine an individual jobs memory consumption on the iSeries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446893/is-there-any-way-to-determine-an-individual-jobs-memory-consumption-on-the-iseri))

But I would like to do something similar to this in C#.  I have not been able to find the right classes to use, in C#.

I just want to fetch all the jobs under a certain subsystem, and retrieve their Job log messages.

I am using VS2008, and have the iSeries installed on my windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JT400 classes are more than a front end to IBM i commands.  They represent, in effect, a client-server application that implements many system APIs and serialises the returned data in a way that Java classes can natively consume it.

There is no .NET version of this functionality.  IBM have chosen to implement this in Java alone.  However, IBM do offer the [.NET Data Provider](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/i/access/windows/dotnet.html) which can be used as the foundation for your own version of this functionality.  Basically, you'd need to run the proper commands to create user spaces, call APIs, read user spaces and delete them when finished - all from .NET.  Not impossible, but it's a pretty significant lift if you've never done anything like that on the IBM i side before.

You might consider calling the Java classes from your .NET application directly:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/339899/Using-jtOpen-from-Net-code-IKVM
- http://www.ikvm.net/